# Angular Material - Mat-Accordion Shadow effect on selection of that Accordion Description Item

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material 14 with Angular 15 and below is the code to display Menu items with mat-nav-list

```
<mat-nav-list role="list">
    <a mat-list-item role="listitem" class="list-item-setting" matTooltipPosition="right" routerLinkActive="active"
    [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="admin-link">
    <mat-icon class="list-item-setting">user1</mat-icon>
    <span>User 1</span>
    </a>

    <a mat-list-item role="listitem" class="list-item-setting" matTooltipPosition="right" routerLinkActive="active"
    [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="admin-link">
    <mat-icon class="list-item-setting">user2</mat-icon>
    <span class="nowrap">User 2</span>
    </a>

    <a mat-list-item role="listitem" class="list-item-setting" matTooltipPosition="right" routerLinkActive="active"
    [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="admin-link">
    <mat-icon class="list-item-setting">user3</mat-icon>
    <span class="nowrap">User 3</span>
    </a>
    <mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle [(expanded)]="panelOpenState" class="mat-elevation-z0">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title style="text-align: left">
          <img src="../../../../assets/images/icon_bell.svg">
          <span class="add-padding-to-mat-panel-header"><a class="list-item-setting" routerLinkActive="active">Submenu
              Accordion</a></span>
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <div>
        <mat-panel-description mat-list-item role="listitem" id="notificationListId"
          class="mat-panel-description-setting"><a class="list-item-setting" routerLinkActive="active"
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">Submenu 1
          </a></mat-panel-description>
        <mat-panel-description mat-list-item role="listitem" id="subscriberGroupsId"
          class="mat-panel-description-setting"><a class="list-item-setting" routerLinkActive="active"
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" style="white-space: nowrap;">Submenu 2</a></mat-panel-description>
        <mat-panel-description mat-list-item role="listitem" id="allSubscribersId"
          class="mat-panel-description-setting"><a class="list-item-setting" routerLinkActive="active">Submenu
            3</a></mat-panel-description>
      </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
</mat-nav-list>
```

And below is the Menu list that appears with this code..

[image: Shadow Band]

The CSS Code related to the Menu is below...

```
.mat-panel-description-setting {
    color: $white;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

.mat-expansion-panel-header {
    padding: 0 16px !important;
}
  
.list-item-setting {
    padding: 0!important;
    padding-left: 16px;
    color: $white;
}

.add-padding-to-mat-panel-header {
    color: $white;
    padding-left: 16px;
}
```

How can I make the same effect for the `Submenu Accordion` Description items on selection of any one of the Submenu items in the list. I mean to say, if user selects Submenu 2, then it should highlight with Band(Shadow effect) that I have shown in the picture for that Submenu 2 item.

I tried using `<mat-nav-list></mat-nav-list>` for the `Accordion Submenu` items and it is not accepting there..

**EDIT**

With the code given in the Answer, I am getting as below screenshot. I have changed your code little bit like - using @HostListener instead of document.addEventListener. The grey background is not going away on click of 2nd Submenu item. And the width is covering only to that text.

[image: Submenu Accordion]

Can anyone throw some light on this..

Comment: @RokBenko Could you please help me on this?

Comment: I don't understand. What's your goal? Do you want to manipulate *Submenu Accordion* or *Submenu 1*, *Submenu 2*, *Submenu 3*? Do you want to change CSS on `:hover`? If user selects *Submenu 2*, what should "highlight"?

Comment: I don't want for Submenu Accordion Title. But on click of any of the Submenu items like Submenu1, Submenu2 or Submenu3 it should be highlighted(Which is similar to selection of User 2 in the attached screenshot). On click of other menu item like User 1, User 2 or Submenu 1 etc, then that should be highlighted.

Comment: @RokBenko Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Include please your css, an [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-accordion-menu-list?file=src%2Fapp%2Faccordion%2Faccordion.component.html) would be ideal.

Comment: @luiscla27 - Added the CSS Code to the Question. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting a more "Angular" approach to this problem as the current solution offered, while it certainly solves the problem, it does leverage what I would consider to be Angular anti patterns.

Leverage `@ViewChildren` to retrieve `ElementRef` from the DOM via the `MatListItem` class.

```js
@ViewChildren(MatListItem, { read: ElementRef }) listItems!: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Import `Renderer2` for styling of the elements.

> Using `Renderer2` ensures vended compilations are compliant with regard to specified targets.

```js
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
```

Function to `hanleSelectionState`.

```js
// Function to reset the background color of all elements
public handleSelectionState(e: any) {
  // loop over all elements to remove any is-active attributes
  this.listItems.forEach((listItem) => {
    this.renderer.removeAttribute(listItem.nativeElement, 'is-active', '');
  });
  // use target on click event to set attribute is-active 
  this.renderer.setAttribute(e.currentTarget, 'is-active', '');
}
```

Add CSS to `styles.scss` for the `is-active` attribute

```css
[is-active] {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

In the HTML bind the `click` event to the `hanleSelectionState` function

```html
<mat-list-item (click)="handleSelectionState($event)">
  <mat-icon class="list-item-setting">email</mat-icon>
  <span class="add-padding">User 1</span>
</mat-list-item>
```

*STACKBLITZ*

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sidenav-xrwfts?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-overview-example.ts